# How to improve the VBA code for converting a monthly salary table of 14 columns to a 4-column dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to convert a salary table of 14 columns including department,job level and 12 months (one column for each month) to a dataset format with 4 columns only -month, department, job level and salary amount. The purpose is to convert the salary table to a database format so that I can create a pivot table based on it or load it to a BI platform to analyse it against actual or budget.

I have written a very "clumsy" VBA code for this purpose which basically is doing a copy, paste and transpose of the salary data line by line to a new sheet. When the lines of salary table becomes too many, the code becomes very time-consuming to run. I am wondering if there is any better VBA coding available to convert the data into the required format? Thanks for the advice!

```
Sub payrollsum()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim e, s As Worksheet
Dim elr As Long

Set s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("payroll Data")
Set e = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll Table")
elr = e.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
slr = s.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
e.Select

For g = 3 To elr
    Range(Cells(g, 3), Cells(g, 14)).Copy
    Range("p6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("p5:aa5") = Cells(g, 2)
    Range("p4:aa4") = Cells(g, 1)
    Range("c2:n2").Copy
    Range("p3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("p3:aa6").Copy
    Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Range("p3:aa6").ClearContents
Next g

e.Range("ab3:ae" & Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
s.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
e.Range("ab3:ae" & Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
End Sub
```

[Salary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QV4N.png)
[Salary dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jraKe.png)

Comment: What you want to do is unpivot the table. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/ show one way to do that with Powerquery. You can find loads of other samples online, including some macros

Comment: If your code is working, this may be a good candidate for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Set sh1 = Sheets("Payroll Table")
Set sh2 = Sheets("payroll Data")
strt = "A"
Set rg = sh1.Range("A3", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
m = sh1.Range("C2", sh1.Range("C2").End(xlToRight)).Value
    For Each cell In rg
    arDL = Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)).Value
    arS = cell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, Application.CountA(m)).Value
    Set oFill = sh2.Range(strt & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    oFill.Resize(Application.CountA(m), 2) = arDL
    oFill.Offset(0, 2).Resize(Application.CountA(m)) = _
    Application.Transpose(m)
    oFill.Offset(0, 3).Resize(Application.CountA(m)) = _
    Application.Transpose(arS)
    Next
End Sub
```

I tested it with around 3200 rows,
it takes less than 5 seconds,
with a result around 38000 rows.